# Mailer Error: Message body empty

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I can't, for the life of me, figure out why I'm receiving this error. Code below:

```
    require_once('lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
                                    $mail = new PHPMailer();
                                    $mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 26;
$mail->Username = "EMAIL@EMAIL.com";
$mail->Password = "scrambled";
$mail->SetFrom('EMAIL@EMAIL.com', 'Web App');
$mail->Subject = "A Transactional Email From Web App";
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->msgHTML($body);
$mail->AddAddress('EMAIL@EMAIL.com', 'Nomination');
                        if($mail->Send()) {
  echo "Message sent!";
} else {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Someone please help!

Comment: why are you setting ishtml() to  false, then stuffing in an html message anyways? totally "These are not the droids you are looking for"...

Comment: Check what `Body` is set to after calling `msgHTML`.

Comment: I realize this might be seen as a similar question to something that has been asked before, but any of the examples I've seen haven't been able to help me solve my issue. I'm also not a programmer, so trying to figure out this problem my boss is having with a website he created for his foundation. Sorry if this is an improper use of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail->Body = 'blablabla';
```

Also

```
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->msgHTML($body);
```

sort of "no. but yes". remove the second line.

Comment: `msgHTML` sets the `Body` property and also sets `isHTML`, so the `isHTML()` call is harmless.

Comment: I tried this, and the page never loads after the form. Also no email is sent :/